# How to detect if data value is nil, when struct properties are optional

Tags: json, swift, generics, codable

Parsing data using Codable don't fail.

when I use generic I want the parsing to fail if the fields are deferent then my object fields

```
struct someStruct: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var age: Int?
}

JSON :
{
    "some_key": 123
}
```

Comment: I want it to fail if the field is not in the json

Comment: And be able to continue if a field value is null

Comment: You're contradicting your own statement. First you want to fail if field (or key) is not in JSON. Then you said you want to continue if field value is nil (which is the same as field is not in JSON as the struct's property value will only be nil if there is no field in JSON). Please provide more information or rephrase your question.

Comment: I am using generic Codable struct so I need to know if I have got all the fields from the JSON

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Codable** to parse data whether it is nil or not. And after that you can check Struct like below for nil value-

```
if let name = yourStruct.name as? String {

} else {
  //nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `Codable` with your struct and when you parse the JSON data, and since your properties in your *struct* are *optional*, you can safe unwrap the values using `if-let` . I Have provided a sample example for the same

```
import Foundation

let jsonData = """
    {
        "some_key": 123
    }
"""

let data = Data(jsonData.utf8)

struct someStruct: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var age: Int?
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let decodedData = try decoder.decode(someStruct.self, from: data)

    // Either use this
    print(decodedData.name ?? "Name not specified")

    // Or use this
    if let name = decodedData.name {
        // Name is not nil
        // Sample Example
        print(name)
    }
    else {
        // Name is nil , Handle the situation accordingly
        // Sample Example
        print("Name not specified")
    }

} catch  {
    print("Could not parse JSON Data")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to `throw` if a field is missing, but continue when the field is specified but `nil`.
You need to implement custom encoding to solve that:

```
enum EncodingError: Error {
    case missing
}

struct Struct: Codable {
    let age: Int
    let name: String?

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case age
        case name
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        // normal decoding
        age = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .age)
        // check if key exists or throw
        guard container.contains(.name) else {
            throw EncodingError.missing
        }
        name = try container.decode(String?.self, forKey: .name)
     }
}

let correctData = """
{
    "age": 34,
    "name": null
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let failData = """
{
    "age": 33
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let encoded = try decoder.decode(Struct.self, from: correctData) // succeeds
    let fail = try decoder.decode(Struct.self, from: failData) // fails
} catch(let error) where error is EncodingError {
    error
} catch {
    error
}
```